# putting a inset box shadow on an image or image within a div

Tags: css

I have an image on my page which i want to put an inset box shadow on. 
I have tried doing this with the image both in, and out, of a div.
Can anyone help me to get an inset box shadow to display?

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="logo">
<img src="images/key.jpg"  width="3%" height="3%"/>
</div>

<a href="scene2.html" class="next">Next</a>
<a href="abduction.html" class="back">Back</a>

<img src="images/scene1.jpg"  width="650" height="650" class="backing"/>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.backing {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-10;
    float:left;
    margin-left:12%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 -50px -50px  #FFF;
        -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 -50px -50px  #FFF;
        -webkit-box-shadow:  0 0 -50px -50px  #FFF;

}

.next {
    position:relative;  
    margin-left:8%;
    z-index:200;
}

.back {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:2%;
    z-index:220;

}
```

Answer (score 17):

Box-shadow inset will not work on image, you need to create a div and give box-shadow to that div and put image inside that div.

You can also use a negative z-index on the img element, and use the box-shadow with inset value on the div element.

```
div {
    position: relative; /* Not required now */
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

div img {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xev7/2/)

Comment: The important bit here seems to be `position:relative`, otherwise the image cannot be placed behind its parent. But unfortunately the image moves behind all other parent objects, if those do not have a negative z-index as well.

Comment: @fschmengler all parent objects... that's gonna break a lot of things. you have to make ALL of the image's parents `position: relative/absolute/fixed` and `z-index: -1`... why doesn't it work if you use a positive z index on the container instead?

Answer (score 10):

Most of the solutions posted here have problems with the parent elements, a simple solution to this, is using pseudo elements:

```css
.box-shadow
{
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 235px;
  margin: 32px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-shadow::after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;   
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-shadow">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/addams11-hp.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

The other answers that propose z-index have an issue if put into context, in my case the image disappeared behind the main div. Preventing this involves setting `z-index: 1;` (and non static position) to all of the ancestor elements, which is problematic, and may break a lot of existing layout.

I found a clean solution that doesn't require having to touch all ancestor elements.

I finally figured it out with the help of [Understanding z-index - The Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

### HTML

The markup stays like this:

```
<div class="box-shadow">
    <img src="/images/graphic.jpg" />
</div>
```

The challenge is to put the wrapper div and the image into a single stacking context. For this you have to apply styles to the **parent** element.

### Stacking Context CSS

According to the linked article, the following elements create a stacking context:

> - the root element (HTML),
> - positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than "auto",
> - a flex item with a z-index value other than "auto",
> - elements with an opacity value less than 1. (See the specification for opacity),
> - elements with a transform value other than "none",
> - elements with a mix-blend-mode value other than "normal",
> - elements with isolation set to "isolate",
> - on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, position: fixed always creates a new stacking context, even when z-index is "auto"
> - specifing any attribute above in will-change even you don't write themselves directly

If we focus on the options that make sense for this use case, we have these alternatives, assuming the parent element **of the `.box-shadow` element** is `#parent`:

#### 1. Positioning and z-index:

This is what I would choose if possible:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

#### 2. Opacity

If the parent element needs to have a different position attribute or adding z-index has unwanted side effects, you can use an opacity value that's *almost* 1, so that it has no visible effect but still creates a stacking context:

```
#parent {
    opacity: 0.999;
}
```

### Finally, the shadow CSS

Then you can apply the shadow on the div and move the img behind it with z-index:

```
.box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 6px white inset;
}
.box-shadow img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. is the `#parent` element `.box-shadow`? if so, then why isn't there opacity, position, and z-index:0 in the `.box-shadow` element? Or is the `#parent` element a wrapper of `.box-shadow`? If so, this is not specified. Also, is `display:block` necessary? I read elsewhere that it makes a difference. If so, why?

Comment: is .box-shadow the #parent? I'm not clear on whether that connection was implied, or if #parent is a third element that wraps .box-shadow.

Comment: No, parent is the parent element of .box-shadow. This can be an existing element or if this doesn't work, an additional wrapper.

Comment: `display: block` is not necessary for the box shadow to work but for exact positioning. I think this is because as an inline-element (i.e. without display:block), you'd have to specify `vertical-align` and `line-height` to not have margins above or below the image.

Comment: So this is a cleaner way than specifying position relative z-index: -1 to every ancestor element, but it still does not get around having to address every ancestor element. Is this correct? Or does the buck stop with the direct parent of .box-shadow, so to speak?

Comment: The latter. Only the direct parent must become a stacking context

Comment: Ah, so that's the elegance behind this solution. It was not apparent to me when you said "The challenge is to put the wrapper div and the image into a single stacking context." This makes it the "correct" solution. I think some marketing is in order to highlight the benefits and elegance of this solution.

Comment: why did you choose opacity over the other options? isolation seems to be designed for this. Does it have issues with browser support? I couldn't get very good google results for this css property. Is it a deprecated relic that roamed once upon a time?

Comment: Yes, as soon as there is better support, isolation is the best option (should have mentioned that). At the moment, it's not the case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It would be very helpful if you had a fiddle demonstrating this solution, the discussion here is confusing.

Comment: `position: fixed` will also do the trick, if you're wanting the main `div` to stay in place when scrolling

Answer (score 8):

Here’s a clean, simple and modern approach of CSS pseudo-elements to place a box shadow *“on top of an image”*, since `img` tags themselves don’t support pseudo-elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box-shadow">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LzBY.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box-shadow {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-shadow::after {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.box-shadow img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

[image: Image with Box Shadow Overlay]

View the accompanying [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rdy9kku/).

Answer (score -3):

```css
.backing {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-10;
    float:left;
    margin-left:12%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 50px  #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 50px  #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 50px  #FFF;

}

.next {
    position:relative;  
    margin-left:8%;
    z-index:200;
}

.back {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:2%;
    z-index:220;

}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="//picsum.photos/100"  width="3%" height="3%"/>
</div>

<a href="scene2.html" class="next">Next</a>
<a href="abduction.html" class="back">Back</a>

<img src="//picsum.photos/650"  width="650" height="650" class="backing"/>
```