# Inset shadow over an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, shadow

I'm trying to create an overlay shadow over an image in CSS but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's the code that I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4Ka/1/

**HTML**

```
<section id="top-container" class="top-column" style="width:1050px; height:420px; ">

<div class="image" style="padding-top: 10px; float:left;"><img src="http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/HD-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" border="0"; width="263"; height="200" style="display: block; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;">
<h4 style="font-size:30px; top: 90px; ">Nature</h4></div>

<div class="image" style="padding-top: 10px; float:left;"><img src="http://www.hdwallpapersart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/tiger_wallpapers_hd_Bengal_Tiger_hd_wallpaper1.jpg" border="0"; width="262"; height="200" style="display: block; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; ">
<h4 style="font-size:30px; top: 90px; ">Bengal Tiger</h4></div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.image { 
  position: relative; 

}

h4 { 
   position: absolute;    
      width: 100%; 
      color: #fff;
      float: left;   
      position: absolute;      
      font-size: 40px;
      font-family: "Oswald";
      text-align: center;
      max-height:auto;
      z-index:20;
      text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
      -moz-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
      -ms-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
      -o-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
      -webkit-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
}
```

I basically want it to look like the one in this website. I tried looking at some tutorials online but it screwed it up real bad so I removed it. I want it to look like the one in this website before and after I hover around the image. Thanks so much to anybody who can help me.

http://vr-zone.com/

Comment: simply add img{display:block; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;    
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000; } to class you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4Ka/4/)**

**css**

```
.image { 
   position: relative; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;    
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #000;

}
```

OR REF **[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771178/putting-a-inset-box-shadow-on-an-image-or-image-within-a-div)**

Answer (score 0):

Your text shadow effect actually seems to work fine, just a few syntactical errors within the html, and need to import the font. Also you don't need to vendor prefix the `text-shadow` rule.

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4Ka/3/).

**Edit**: I agree with the comment above - Yes, if you are trying to give box-shadow to the image, then use `box-shadow`.