# Inset shadow over small iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

Hi there Stack overflow,

I'm having a small issue with displaying an inset box-shadow over an iframe.
I have a review iFrame but it has a border. I wanted to display an inset box-shadow around it to counter that.

[image]

I followed the steps shown here: [Inset shadow over an image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064504/inset-shadow-over-an-image-in-css)

But that resulted in the shadow being full width over the entire screen.
The iFrame is sitting within a div currently.

[image]

This is how it currently looks, the goal is to get rid of that border, it is styled within the iframe so I can't access the style code.

Hopefully someone here knows how to solve it.

Kind regards,
Roel

Comment: If you can wrap the iframe into an additional element, then this should probably be easily achievable by using a negative margin, and cutting off the wrapper element's overflow. https://jsfiddle.net/ozy7u104/

Comment: Thank you kindly, this worked like a charm. I had no idea it could be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Itis very easy to do, like this:

```css
.frame {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 2px 7px 5px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/cqLws4fa/)