# How To Get Shadow With Certain Opacity Over Images CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this row of images:

https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1263/

What I'm trying to do is to get a shadow with this opacity over the top of all of the images:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
```

Eventually, I would like to set it up so that when you hover over an image, the opacity drops and a link on top ("View Image") appears. I've tried adding the following styles to my CSS:

```
.thumbnail-row {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 40px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);   
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
}

.thumbnail-image {
    display: inline-block;
    /*width: 14.286%;*/
    /*height: 50px;*/
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4000px rgba(27,61,88,.5); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);   
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
}
```

But no effect. See this most recent attempt:

https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1264/

Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't inset box-shadow work over images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414925/why-doesnt-inset-box-shadow-work-over-images)

Comment: You wont use box-shadow for this. What you need to do is place a div with rgba values over top of each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo to do that

```css
.thumbnail-row {
  display: flex;
}
.thumbnail-row div {
  position: relative;
}
.thumbnail-row div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(27,61,88,.5);
}
.thumbnail-image {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  }
  
@media (max-width: 425px) {
  .thumbnail-row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row thumbnail-row">
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/mNoKbYK.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/8b2sb03.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ac11pRH.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/DgNt5MQ.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/SG0bpMU.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/x1DxQwd.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/YcnOqR1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end row-->
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be halfway working - the shadow isn't completely over the image, it just seems to be over the top half.

Comment: @HappyHands31 Well you wrote _over the top of the images_ ... still, just increase both the size of the pseudo and shadow and you can place it where you want

Comment: Oh I meant 'over the top' as in on top of.

Comment: @HappyHands31 Yeah, now I got that ... updated my answer :)

Comment: @HappyHands31 well can't you than simply edit the boxShadow?

Comment: @LGSon Thank you!