# Getting Overlay / Shadow With 50% Opacity Over Images With CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an overlay or box shadow on top of a row of images. Then when you hover over these images, the opacity of the shadow should change from 0.5 to 0.8 for that image. I have already tried the pseudo technique suggested here:

[How To Get Shadow With Certain Opacity Over Images CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683635/how-to-get-shadow-with-certain-opacity-over-images-css)

And applied styles to the divs beneath the images as it was suggested here:

[Why doesn't inset box-shadow work over images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414925/why-doesnt-inset-box-shadow-work-over-images)

Me + several other people haven't been able to figure this out.

The goal is to get the images to look the same as the other three images above the row - the picture of the business presentation, the picture of the business meeting, and the picture of the businesswoman. Each of them have an initial box shadow over them with 50% opacity - then when you hover over the buttons (see my work, contact, and visit store), the opacity over the image should change from 50% to 80%. We want that same technique to be applied to the images in the row.

HTML:

```
<div class="row thumbnail-row">
<div class="my-work-image" id="margin-left-image">
  <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/hamburger-thumbnail.jpg" />
    <div class="img__description_layer">
      <span class="img__description">The Hamburger Collection</span>
    </div>
</div>   
<div class="my-work-image">
  <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/yoyomoi-thumbnail.jpg" />
   <div class="img__description_layer">
      <span class="img__description">YoYoMoi</span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
  <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/dogs-thumbnail.jpg" />
   <div class="img__description_layer">
      <span class="img__description">Dogs On Duty</span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
  <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/gateway-thumbnail.jpg" />
   <div class="img__description_layer">
      <span class="img__description">Gateway Web Design</span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
  <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/chameleon-thumbnail.jpg" />
   <div class="img__description_layer">
      <span class="img__description">Chameleon Web Solutions</span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
  <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/adrienne-thumbnail.jpg" />
   <div class="img__description_layer">
      <span class="img__description">Adrienne Levin Coleman</span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="my-work-image">
  <img class="thumbnail-image" src="/wp-content/themes/gatewaywebdesign/assets/images/castaway-thumbnail.jpg" />
   <div class="img__description_layer">
      <span class="img__description">Castaway Vacations</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4000px rgba(27, 61, 88, 0.5) inset;
}

.thumbnail-row div::after {
  position: relative;
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;   
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4000px rgba(27, 61, 88, 0.5) inset;
}

.thumbnail-image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/ 
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4000px rgba(27,61,88,.5)!important;*/
}

.my-work-image{
  position:relative;
}  

.img__description_layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;    /*change it to 50%, if you want the text only shows in the half part */
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(27,61,88, 0.8);
  color: #ffffff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4000px rgba(27, 61, 88, 0.5) inset;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.4s, visibility ease-in-out 0.4s;
  /*transition: box-shadow 0.4s ease-in-out;*/
}

.my-work-image:hover .img__description_layer {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.img__description {
  transition: .2s;
  transform: translateY(1em);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.my-work-image:hover .img__description {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#margin-left-image {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1273/)

Any other ideas for getting the images to have an initial box shadow over them?

Comment: like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/1275/

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes exactly - what style did you add?

Comment: Cool I'll submit an answer

Comment: Oh z-index - but yes an answer would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `box-shadow` isn't showing because the `box-shadow` is on the parent of the `img`s, so the  `img`s are covering the `box-shadow`. You can move the `img`s behind the parent by adding `position: relative; z-index: -1;`

```css
.thumbnail-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4000px rgba(27, 61, 88, 0.5) inset;
}

.thumbnail-row div::after {
  position: relative;
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;   
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4000px rgba(27, 61, 88, 0.5) inset;
}

.thumbnail-image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  /*opacity: 0.5;*/ 
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4000px rgba(27,61,88,.5)!important;*/
}
  
.my-work-image{
  position:relative;
}  

.img__description_layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;    /*change it to 50%, if you want the text only shows in the half part */
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(27,61,88, 0.8);
  color: #ffffff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4000px rgba(27, 61, 88, 0.5) inset;
  /* transition effect. not necessary */
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.4s, visibility ease-in-out 0.4s;
  /*transition: box-shadow 0.4s ease-in-out;*/
}

.my-work-image:hover .img__description_layer {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.img__description {
  transition: .2s;
  transform: translateY(1em);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.my-work-image:hover .img__description {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#margin-left-image {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.thumbnail-image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row thumbnail-row">
    <div class="my-work-image" id="margin-left-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/mNoKbYK.jpg" />
        <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">The Hamburger Collection</span>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/8b2sb03.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">YoYoMoi</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ac11pRH.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">Dogs On Duty</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/DgNt5MQ.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">Gateway Web Design</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/SG0bpMU.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">Chameleon Web Solutions</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/x1DxQwd.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">Adrienne Levin Coleman</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-work-image">
      <img class="thumbnail-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/YcnOqR1.jpg" />
       <div class="img__description_layer">
          <span class="img__description">Castaway Vacations</span>
       </div>
    </div>  
  </div><!--end row-->
```