# inset blur not working? CSS

Tags: css

I've been trying to do an inset blur on an image, from what I was reading there are two ways that are common to do this. I've tried both ways.

What I have now, is I wrapped the image in a div, and was attempting to use z-index to place the div with the blur above the image, however, I am not seeing the div at all.

```
#mainpicdiv {
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
width: 100%;
margin-top: 3%;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

#mainpic {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 3%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0%;
position: relative;
z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your code?

Comment: A great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414925/why-doesnt-inset-box-shadow-work-over-images. Basically the inset border you are adding will always be BELOW the image. Instead, put it on top in an absolutely positioned container. The post describes this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a full height and width psuedo-element added to the div that wraps the image. `img` tags do not support box shadows

```
#mainpicdiv {
  position: relative;
}

#mainpicdiv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
}

#mainpicdiv > img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hz70mc13/1/