# Shadow on image

Tags: html, css

I have an image and need to create shadow inside image. I mean I need to create transparent block which will be over image and image will be dim. 
I have this css:

```
img {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #000;
opacity: 0.2;
}
```

but it does not work as I want. How can I solve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414925/why-doesnt-inset-box-shadow-work-over-images

Comment: https://www.dailysmarty.com/posts/how-to-darken-an-image-with-css

Comment: Hope this article could help you - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try This Website. I have used it for most box shaddow thing just to get a better visual and see what I want. https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #000;
```

The code effect is like this picture

[image]

If you want to cover picture using mask, you can use a opacity and dark element cover it.