# Display an inner shadow inside ion-avatar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

Displaying an outer shadow on an `ion-avatar` item works fine, but when trying to display an inner shadow, nothing happens.

Here is [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic5-avatar-inner-shadow) of this problem:

[image]

I tried to apply the inner-shadow on the `img` inside the `ion-avatar` but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a fix](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic5-avatar-inner-shadow-fix) that was based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794582/5486116).

The idea is to place the inner shadow inside the `:after` pseudo element:

```css
ion-avatar {
  position: relative;
  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px 0 #000000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```