# box-shadow won't display on image

Tags: html, css

I am creating a windows 95 style window, that contains an image.

**My problem**: the image inside the window should have a box-shadow inset but it won't display.

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

[this is how the image looks like **atm**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26F3B.png)

[this is how the image **should** look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtZA2.png)

https://codepen.io/roeylu/pen/rNmmxJM

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/98.css">

<div class="window" style="width: 600px;">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <div class="title-bar-text" style="margin-right: 18px; font-family: 'blink'; letter-spacing: .7px;">
      <b>window</b>
    </div>
    <div class="title-bar-controls">
      <button aria-label="Minimize"></button>
      <button aria-label="Maximize"></button>
      <button aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="window-body" style="font-size: 13px; letter-spacing: .36px; word-spacing: -3px; margin: 5px 3px 3px 3px;">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://www.ladymakeup.com/js/lightbox/img/demopage/image-3.jpg" style="width: 100%;
    <!-- this is the part not displaying -->
                 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px #fff, 
                             inset 1px 1px grey, 
                             inset 0px 0px #dfdfdf, 
                             inset 1px 2px #0a0a0a;" alt="image">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414925/why-doesnt-inset-box-shadow-work-over-images

Comment: add a padding bigger than the shadow size, and you will see it. it is actually rendered below the image, the padding will allow to see it.

Comment: could you please demonstrate how to do it code wise?

Answer (score 0):

When give shadow effect in html CSS you need to used  "top-bottom, right-left, blur color ". Give blur value to see spread of shadow color.

Comment: I've created a snippet in the question post. You should copy it to your answer and make the changes you describe to demonstrate your solution.

Comment: aren't top right left bottom set automatically by order?