# How can I add inside box-shadow to an image in css?

Tags: html, css

How can I add inside bottom shadow to an image using css?

```
.example > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 5px red;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

Comment: This is answered in previous old SO threads; there are workarounds. Look at the answers here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414925/why-doesnt-inset-box-shadow-work-over-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414925/why-doesnt-inset-box-shadow-work-over-images). IMHO, I would try the `mix-blend-mode: multiply` trick first since it doesn't involve extra elements. After this, probably have an extra element for a shadow layer floating on top is the next best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate a pseudo element to be used as an overlay.

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
.example::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px red;
}
.example > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `inset-box-shadow` on `.example` and just set `img` to `z-index: -1;`.

```css
.example {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px red;
}

.example>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm, inset bottom shadow - could work like this

```css
.example {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -20px 25px -20px red;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='example'>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can check out each attribute box-shadow is able to take, tweek around !
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp