# Inner shadow for thumbnail box

Tags: html, css

Here is my site http://goo.gl/MeCxv2 when I have my porfolio's thumbnails on the main page and I want to add an inner shadow for all thumbnail boxes. I want to get like this http://goo.gl/L80HAx but with CSS instead of photoshop :D

So, I try to do like this:

```
.rollover-project hover-ready { 
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not even sure, that the class .rollover-project hover-ready is correct.

Could you please to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] Since [.] is used for selecting class name you will have to use it wherever you use class name, so if you want to select 2 class names it should be `.rollover-project.hover-ready` OR `.hover-ready.rollover-project` instead of `.rollover-project hover-ready`

Refer the below link for help on CSS Selectors
[W3Schools - CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

2] The box-shadow is not applied on the correct element; it should be applied on the class of the main box element,

```
<div class="wf-cell category-31 isotope-item">
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by @r8n5n, if you apply the box-shadow to the classes `.rollover-project.hover-ready` i.e. the inner box, it will be overlapped by the thumbnail in the `<a>` tag, and as suggested by him you've 2 options

i] Add the box-shadow to the parent/outer element (which was my suggestion)
ii] Add a padding so that there is some space to show the box-shadow.

Since you want the box-shadow of 1px, add the `padding:1px` and see the effect. Similar example on another thread - [putting a inset box shadow on an image or image within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771178/putting-a-inset-box-shadow-on-an-image-or-image-within-a-div)

Comment: .wf-cell category-31 isotope-item {
} This way doesn't work too.

Comment: it can be applied to any unique class name, if not apply it to combination `.wf-cell.category-31.isotope-item {}` if it identifies the thumbnail properly. You can modify the css and test it out.

Comment: Well, we have the progress! Little bit strange but... :)

Comment: Great. So you got the point what needs to be done to achieve the output. What is strange?

Comment: Strange is, that the shadow is not around of thumbnail but around the thumbnail+padding..? http://goo.gl/MeCxv2

Comment: Added the padding: 1px to .wf-cell.category-31.isotope-item - result - there is no padding now :)

Answer (score 3):

are you missing a '.' in your selector for hover-ready?

```
.rollover-project.hover-ready{

}
```

**Edit**
Looking at this a little more, the image inside your anchor is covering up the inset border. You could try adding a little padding to the element to reveal the shadow or re-ordering your elements/applying the shadow to a different element

e.g.

```
.rollover-project.hover-ready{
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: no, there is no dot here. Anyway .rollover-project.hover-ready doesn't work too. Maybe I take wrong class with browser inspect element option?

Comment: @Merkucio dot is referenced only in CSS,not in HTML.

Comment: I added this in dev tools and got it to work 
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
padding: 10px;

Comment: I believe, but the question is, why it doesn't work here )

Comment: Like I said in the answer, the image in the <a> is covering the inset shadow, change it to an outer (remove the word inset) and you will see it.

Comment: @r8n5n is right. You can change the padding to 1px to remove extra padding and get the box-shadow inset effect.